# A map function how to use the pre-reduce result in MapReduce

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

I'm writing a program that has three steps of MapReduce operation. so I wrote three Mappers and three Reducers function, function names are map1，map2，map3 and reduce1，reduce2，reduce3; step 1 is composed of map1 and reduce1, step2 is composed of map2 and reduce2, step3 is composed of map3 and reduce3；if I want to use both reduce1 and reduce2s' results in map3, how to write map3?
Thanks.

Comment: As long as the data outputs from `r1` and `r2` are the same format, ie `SequenceFileOutputFormat<Text,Text>` for example, you can just add the two outputs as input paths and it will be fine. If they aren't the same you'll need to use `MultipleInputs`.

Comment: can you explain it to me with an example? I am new here, so I cannot catch the point. Thank you very much.

Comment: is the output of reduce1 and reduce2 formatted in the same way? if yes, just add both input paths, instead of using one input path for map3. if not, you need to use MultipleInputs as Binary Nerd suggests, to handle each output in a different mapper (so map3 needs two different mappers, one for each input). Take a look at the class MultipleInputs for more details...